# Is there a "do...while" Loop in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a Java bean named Category which has two variables of the same type Category named respectively parentCategory and childCategory.

Using HQL, I had no trouble getting the parent and child categories from myCategory.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Category getChildCategory(int id) {
    return (Category) hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory()
                                       .getCurrentSession()
                                       .createQuery("SELECT cat.childCategory From Category cat WHERE cat.id= :id");
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Category getParentCategory(int id) {

return (Category) hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory()
                                   .getCurrentSession()
                                   .createQuery("SELECT cat.parentCategory From Category cat WHERE cat.id= :id");
```

}

What I would like to do now is to get all the parents and children categories from a category. The idea is to keep looping until category.getParentCategory() is null. But I don't know how to express this in HQL. Any ideas?

Comment: No there is none.

Comment: I am confused about your question, I see the methods getChildCategory and  getParentCategory currently get data from Category with parameter is Id. So if you want to get all, just change your HQL to "From Category" and return it as a List.